# Files and or directories keep getting deleted from CENT OS file server

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

Im using CENT OS 7 on a file server. On that file server, I have a directory that is used by an application at my company to store files. When that directory is deleted the application is not able to function properly. The issue is also very sporadic. It occurs once every 2-3 months. Could it be an issue with permissions? I have used 2 different permissions schemes and have listed them below. The first one was used and the directories were deleted twice. The second one was used but the directories have not been deleted as of yet, possibly indicating the issue is solved?

The following permissions were added:

```
chmod 750 /Bac/BacFileStore/directory
chmod -R 0777 /Bac/bacFileStore/directory
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a backup/archival process that operates on this directory?

Comment: I'll check and see if there are any backup/archival processes. Thank you.

Comment: So I have never actually viewed the archive files in a Linux machine before. I tried looking for the exact command, but I also realized I'm a bit unsure of where those files are located. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: That's a bit too broad, to be honest. You should check with your local system administrator. The process would usually involve a script or an external tool. Another server is also usually involved as the target data store.

Answer (score 1):

Changing permissions on a directory will never be a cause of it getting deleted. Some program or person must delete it explicitly. So the answer to your question is "No", it's no issue with permissions.

Maybe some 'evil' person deleted the directory if it knew the password of the owner of the directory. Even worse: with your new permissions '0777' any person who has access to the file server can delete any file in the `/Bac/bacFileStore/directory` directory. You should maybe not keep it like that. '750' or maybe '755' (latter if anyone shall be allowed to access the directory) would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Centos has Gnu `chmod`, so you can use symbolic mode. It is much easier to understand. `chmod -R ugo-w /Bac/bacFileStore/directory` (remove write permission for user, group, and other).

Note that the owner and root (and any one with the appropriate capability), can change the mode, and remove.
Note that permission to remove a file, is permission to write to the containing directory (see also stick-bit, if multiple users can write to a directory).

Therefore it may be necessary to change the ownership and permissions, of the files, and the containing directory.

## Detecting when files go missing

You can use `inotify-wait` to detect when the files go missing. You will need to leave this running, it will wake-up when the files change.

Answer (score 0):

Setting 777 permissions grants r/w to everyone who has access to your file server - including deletions. This may be how you want to set up your file server. However, having your application write here as well can be problematic. Is it simply writing files out to your file server or is there other work the app is doing here? If so, I would suggest you configure the application to use a directory not available to the file server. 
If someone deletes a file in use by your application, you will have issues. Also, the file deleted that is in use by your app will not truly be deleted until the process is finished with that file.